# REST API doesn't give data when run with python using for loop, but when ran indivually with python able to get data

Tags: rest, python-requests

The code below adds path-variable to the endpoint and makes a GET request

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

url = "https://LINK/fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/invoices/"

headers = {
            'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }

f =  open("ID's.text","r")

for i in f:
    x = i.strip()
    x = str(x)
    if x:
        Nurl = str(url + i)
        print(Nurl)
        response_raw = requests.get(Nurl, headers = headers, auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user_abc', 'abc123'))
        print(response_raw)

f.close()
```

The issue is When I run the endpoint in a loop, I'm getting `Response<403>`
But when I run the same endpoint seperately with no loop, I got the Expected result.
Also the last iteration of the run did gave `Response<200>`

```
Output:

<Response [403]>
<Response [403]>
<Response [403]>
<Response [403]>
<Response [403]>
<Response [403]>
<Response [403]>
<Response [403]>
<Response [403]>
<Response [200]>
```

I'm new to API's, just couldn't understand what wrong am doing
Please help.

Comment: can you print i during each iteration and print the contents of the response?

Comment: @HunterBoyd So I just checked that. In the file I was opening, after every value there is a new empty line except for last value, and those empty lines were not being stripped, and being appended to the URL which is what  causing issue. TYSM for the insight.
I thought strip will strip off the empty line, My bad.

Answer (score 0):

if every line in "ID's.text" is one ID, you have to remove '\n' for each one.
example:

```
for i in f:
    x = i.replace('\n','').strip()
    if x:
```

or you can read the full file content and split it with '\n'.
example:

```
for i in [each_id for each_id  in f.read().split('\n') if each_id.strip()]:
    xxx
```